# Горизонтальная прокрутка колесиком

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

У меня есть блок с `overflow: auto` И там горизонтальный скроллинг. Можно ли сделать, чтобы когда наводишь на него мышкой и крутишь колесиком, оно скроллилось?

Может какой атрибут html5? Если нужен JS, то лучше jQuery

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ловите скролл с помощью `mousewheel` и передвигаете с помощью: `element.scrollLeft`

Comment: @inferus-vv  http://jsfiddle.net/Scfe2/

Comment: Я раньше хотел в таком случае добавить еще одно колесико к мышке, где-нть сбоку, чтобы большим пальцем прокручивать.

Comment: Вот [тут есть пример](http://learn.javascript.ru/play/tutorial/browser/events/wheel.html), как отлавливать события колесика мыши. Думаю, что разобравшись с ним, у вас не возникнет проблем с реализацией вашей задачи.

Comment: @lampa Хм.. Вроде работает, но есть проблема, что весь сайт все равно скроллится вниз.

Comment: @inferus-vv добавьте в обработчик: return false;

Comment: в jQuery delta вроде-бы не приведена, чем не устраивает мой ответ ?

Comment: только не работает :)

Comment: @eicto мне кажется, у вас пример слишком громоздкий, проще использовать mousewheel.

Comment: @lampa Я нашел проблему! Все дело в версии jQuery! Эту вещь можно заточить под версию 1.7.2?

Comment: @inferus-vv скорее всего просто для определенной версии jQuery своя mousewheel библиотека.

Comment: @lampa, смысл примера в том,  чтобы скролл был честным, в соответствии с настройками ОС и браузера.

Answer (score 0):

"честный горизонтальный скрол" - таскаем за мышкой невидимое окошко, со внутренней высотой равной внутренней ширине того что будем скролить горизонтально.
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DcyWD/

CSS:

```
#pass {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 background: black;
 opacity: 0;    
 overflow-x: scroll;
 z-index: 10000;
}
#inner {
  height: 10000px;
}
#text {
 width: 10000px;   
}
```

JS:

```
var pass=$('#pass');
//пропускаем нажатия мыши, чтобы можно было выделять текст
pass.mousedown(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $this=$(this);
    $this.css('z-index','-1000');
   $('document').trigger(e);
   $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $this.css('z-index','1000');
    })
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e,d){
pass.css('top',e.clientY);
pass.css('left',e.clientX);    
})
    pass.scroll(function(){
    console.log(pass.scrollTop());
    $('body').scrollLeft(pass.scrollTop());
    })
```

другой пример, что-то похожее - превращение вертикальной позиции элемента в атрибуты css

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/

оба примера тестировал только в chrome, думаю с ними еще проблема при зуме может быть,